# Sorting images by custom order - Lightroom Plugin

Tags: plugins, lightroom

I want to sort images in a custom order. The folks at https://www.excire.com/de/excire-search-2/ got this working, they can sort images by e.g. similarity to an input image.

I have a plugin calculating the wanted order, but I don't know how to sort them in Lightroom. Writing the index as metadata does work but it is then only selectable, not sortable.

Is there a way to set the custom metadata to be searchable? Or how could this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by putting the results of a custom sort either into a new collection, or re-adding them to the current collection.